# How to get an instance of Mail in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was just going through the Mail sending documentation in laravel **[HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail)**:

The first example that i come across is the below example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send an e-mail reminder to the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendEmailReminder(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

            $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
        });
    }
}
```

Now where exactly is `$m` defined here ? And if its not defined how do i get an instance of the Mail Laravel service ??

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in [code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php#L157) the `send` function is defined as `public function send($view, array $data, $callback)` so `$m` is defined in the call back holding the initiated mail object.